# Non Floating Figures

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I want to stop my figures floating, but I still want to be able to have the caption to the side of them; mainly to save space and for presentation.

The only way I know how to get the figure caption to the side of an image is as follows;

```
\begin{SCfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=80mm]{image.png}
  \caption{This text is added at the side of the image as a figure description.}
\end{SCfigure}
```

But, these always float which as it turns out isn't saving space and it just looks messy, so I want this sort of layout for my figures, but I want to fix their position.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obviously, place a figure where I placed the table, and note that in the `\captionof` argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
     hello & world\\
     hello & world\\
     hello & world\\
     hello & world\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hspace{1em}
\parbox[c]{2in}{\captionof{table}{my table has this somewhat long caption}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For figures, a `\raisebox` may be necessary for vertical positioning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\raisebox{-.8in}{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{figure}}
\hspace{1em}
\parbox[c]{2in}{\captionof{figure}{my table has this somewhat long caption}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah I think I'll delete mine, you seem to have covered most of it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `float`and `floatrow` package: the first defines a H option for the placement that enforces the float placement "here" ([!h] meaning "here, as much as possible). With the second, you can define caption settings.

So, if you want all your figures to have a sideways caption (and not other floats), you could write in your preamble, if you want your caption to be, say, on the left side, at the top of the figure,  something like:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=beside, capbesideposition={left,top}}
```

In the document body, just write:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=80mm]{image.png}
  \caption{This text is added at the side of the image as a figure description.}
\end{figure}
```

If you want sideways captions only for some  floats, don't write \floatsetup… in the preamble, and write:

```
\thisfloatsetup{capposition=beside, capbesideposition={left,top}}
\begin{figure}[H]
   .............
```

Of course you have access to may other settings (fonts, width of cation, &c.)

Comment: This causes an error for me that the `floatrow` and `float` packages should not be used together.

Answer (score 2):

To stop figures from floating outside the section, I recommend using the [`placeins` package](http://lexfridman.com/blogs/research/2011/03/06/prevent-figures-from-floating-outside-sections-in-latex/).

To put the caption to the side of the picture, use `minipage` inside `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`. For example:

```
\usepackage[section,subsection,subsubsection]{placeins}
%...
%...
\FloatBarrier
    \begin{figure}[htbp!]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{The caption of the picture on the right side}
            \label{fig:pictureonright}
            \end{minipage}%
            \begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=6cm]{figs/youpicture}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
```

Hope it works for you!

PS: If you want to read more on working with graphics in LaTeX and PdfLaTeX, here is a recommended source: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much, @AdamLiter. This tip works great and the links are very useful to me.

Comment: I get `LaTeX Error: "Unknown option 'subsection' for package 'placeins'"` (and for subsubsection) from pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018). :/

Comment: I get the same error for pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019).

Comment: Yeah, only "section" is a valid option, and it only works if the existing \section command is fairly normal. To insert \FloatBarrier in other commands, I'd suggest using the xpatch package and `\xpretocmd{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier}{}{}`.