# Mismatch between code and position of figures with LATEX

Tags: floats

I use the following code to add figures:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{orig.png}
    \caption{pic}
    %\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{figure}
```

However the figure doesn't appear where it should. For example:

```
\subsection{A}

\subsubsection{a}

text

[the figure code]

\subsubsection{b}

text

[This is where the figure shows up]

\subsection{B}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: try using `\begin{figure}[htp]` instead. The `h` part is missing in the default (which is the same as `tbp`).

Comment: The _only_ reason to put anything in a floating environment such as figure is to allow latex to move it to obtain better page breaks.

Comment: See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD)

Comment: See [Non Floating Figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162284/23160)